# ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'wtools2'

Tags: python-3.x, django

I am trying to run my Django Application, getting following error when using this command Line.

```
python manage.py runserver
```

**Error**

```
        (venv) F:\ATSG\FrontEnd\wtoolgui\wtools2>python manage.py runserver
    Traceback (most recent call last):
    File "F:\ATSG\FrontEnd\wtoolgui\venv\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\base.py", line 354, in run_from_argv
        self.execute(*args, **cmd_options)
    File "F:\ATSG\FrontEnd\wtoolgui\venv\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\commands\runserver.py", line 61, in execute
        super().execute(*args, **options)
    File "F:\ATSG\FrontEnd\wtoolgui\venv\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\base.py", line 398, in execute
        output = self.handle(*args, **options)
    File "F:\ATSG\FrontEnd\wtoolgui\venv\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\commands\runserver.py", line 68, in handle
        if not settings.DEBUG and not settings.ALLOWED_HOSTS:
    File "F:\ATSG\FrontEnd\wtoolgui\venv\lib\site-packages\django\conf\__init__.py", line 82, in __getattr__
        self._setup(name)
    File "F:\ATSG\FrontEnd\wtoolgui\venv\lib\site-packages\django\conf\__init__.py", line 69, in _setup
        self._wrapped = Settings(settings_module)
    File "F:\ATSG\FrontEnd\wtoolgui\venv\lib\site-packages\django\conf\__init__.py", line 170, in __init__
        mod = importlib.import_module(self.SETTINGS_MODULE)
    File "C:\Users\Muhammad Usman\.pyenv\pyenv-win\versions\3.10.0\lib\importlib\__init__.py", line 126, in import_module
        return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)
    File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1050, in _gcd_import
    File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1027, in _find_and_load
    File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 992, in _find_and_load_unlocked
    File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 241, in _call_with_frames_removed
    File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1050, in _gcd_import
    File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1027, in _find_and_load
    File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1004, in _find_and_load_unlocked
    ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'wtools2'

    During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

    Traceback (most recent call last):
    File "F:\ATSG\FrontEnd\wtoolgui\wtools2\manage.py", line 47, in <module>
        execute_from_command_line(sys.argv)
    File "F:\ATSG\FrontEnd\wtoolgui\venv\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\__init__.py", line 419, in execute_from_command_line
        utility.execute()
    File "F:\ATSG\FrontEnd\wtoolgui\venv\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\__init__.py", line 413, in execute
        self.fetch_command(subcommand).run_from_argv(self.argv)
    File "F:\ATSG\FrontEnd\wtoolgui\venv\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\base.py", line 367, in run_from_argv
        connections.close_all()
    File "F:\ATSG\FrontEnd\wtoolgui\venv\lib\site-packages\django\db\utils.py", line 208, in close_all
        for alias in self:
    File "F:\ATSG\FrontEnd\wtoolgui\venv\lib\site-packages\django\utils\connection.py", line 73, in __iter__
        return iter(self.settings)
    File "F:\ATSG\FrontEnd\wtoolgui\venv\lib\site-packages\django\utils\functional.py", line 48, in __get__
        res = instance.__dict__[self.name] = self.func(instance)
    File "F:\ATSG\FrontEnd\wtoolgui\venv\lib\site-packages\django\utils\connection.py", line 45, in settings
        self._settings = self.configure_settings(self._settings)
    File "F:\ATSG\FrontEnd\wtoolgui\venv\lib\site-packages\django\db\utils.py", line 144, in configure_settings
        databases = super().configure_settings(databases)
    File "F:\ATSG\FrontEnd\wtoolgui\venv\lib\site-packages\django\utils\connection.py", line 50, in configure_settings
        settings = getattr(django_settings, self.settings_name)
    File "F:\ATSG\FrontEnd\wtoolgui\venv\lib\site-packages\django\conf\__init__.py", line 82, in __getattr__
        self._setup(name)
    File "F:\ATSG\FrontEnd\wtoolgui\venv\lib\site-packages\django\conf\__init__.py", line 69, in _setup
        self._wrapped = Settings(settings_module)
    File "F:\ATSG\FrontEnd\wtoolgui\venv\lib\site-packages\django\conf\__init__.py", line 170, in __init__
        mod = importlib.import_module(self.SETTINGS_MODULE)
    File "C:\Users\Muhammad Usman\.pyenv\pyenv-win\versions\3.10.0\lib\importlib\__init__.py", line 126, in import_module
        return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)
    File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1050, in _gcd_import
    File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1027, in _find_and_load
    File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 992, in _find_and_load_unlocked
    File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 241, in _call_with_frames_removed
    File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1050, in _gcd_import
    File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1027, in _find_and_load
    File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1004, in _find_and_load_unlocked
    ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'wtools2'
```

This is my Directory Structure

```
    Directory: F:\ATSG\FrontEnd\wtoolgui


    Mode                 LastWriteTime         Length Name
    ----                 -------------         ------ ----
    d-----         11/1/2023   8:14 PM                .idea
    d-----         11/1/2023   4:28 PM                mods
    d-----         11/1/2023   5:08 PM                venv
    d-----         11/1/2023   8:09 PM                wtools2
    -a----         11/1/2023   4:56 PM           1107 .gitignore
    -a----         11/1/2023   4:56 PM           5698 az_requirements.txt                                                                                                              
    -a----         11/1/2023   4:56 PM            455 django.wsgi
    -a----         11/1/2023   4:56 PM           1668 manage.py
    -a----         11/1/2023   4:56 PM           3905 newsql queries.txt                                                                                                               
    -a----         11/1/2023   4:28 PM             18 README.md
    -a----         11/1/2023   4:56 PM           6781 req.txt
    -a----         11/1/2023   4:56 PM           7029 requirements.txt
```

Directory: F:\ATSG\FrontEnd\wtoolgui\wtools2

```
    Mode                 LastWriteTime         Length Name
    ----                 -------------         ------ ----
    d-----         11/1/2023   6:25 PM                apps
    d-----         11/1/2023   6:29 PM                celerydir
    d-----         11/1/2023   4:56 PM                convex
    d-----         11/1/2023   6:25 PM                libs
    d-----         11/1/2023   4:56 PM                nvd3
    d-----         11/1/2023   4:56 PM                static
    d-----         11/1/2023   4:56 PM                templates
    d-----         11/1/2023   8:09 PM                __pycache__                                                                                                                      
    -a----         11/1/2023   6:17 PM          18216 constants.py
    -a----         11/1/2023   4:28 PM             96 context_processors.py
    -a----         11/1/2023   4:56 PM            871 crontab_config.py
    -a----         11/1/2023   6:17 PM           6318 dinconfig.py
    -a----         11/1/2023   4:56 PM           9570 function.py
    -a----         11/1/2023   7:53 PM           1714 manage.py
    -a----         11/1/2023   4:28 PM           1778 messages.py
    -a----         11/1/2023   4:56 PM          17022 middleware.py
    -a----         11/1/2023   4:56 PM           1322 requirements.txt
    -a----         11/1/2023   4:56 PM           1789 routers.py                                                                                                                       
    -a----         11/1/2023   8:09 PM          21630 settings.py
    -a----         11/1/2023   4:28 PM            304 setup.py
    -a----         11/1/2023   6:17 PM           1196 strings.json
    -a----         11/1/2023   4:56 PM           5674 urls.py
    -a----         11/1/2023   4:56 PM          24773 views.py
    -a----         11/1/2023   4:56 PM            349 _celery.py
    -a----         11/1/2023   4:56 PM            225 __init__.py
```

Also the same project runs on Pycharm
[image: PyCharm Django Setting]

Comment: The root shoold be `\wtoolgui`, so one level up.

Comment: But in PyCharm, it runs when I set wtools2 as ROOT